# Why there are less itineraries from BargainFinderMax_ADRQ

Tags: sabre

A few days back I was having an issue with the records from the sabre for alternate days, now finally I got the records but the records are much less, like when I search roundtrip for AD3 for 7 days duration the only 49 itineraries and for oneway AD1 9 records from the sabre. is there something wrong with the XML request.

below is the XML request

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><m:MessageHeader xmlns:m="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <m:From>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">http://deluxholidaysnew.local</m:PartyId>
            </m:From>
            <m:To>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">https://sws-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com</m:PartyId>
            </m:To>
            <m:CPAId>****</m:CPAId>
            <m:ConversationId>V1@dXIIccWqTWCaYP1Nil099DvScws2Fuy2ufg1d2Zb@5b8aa3bcbfe2c@http://test.local</m:ConversationId>
            <m:Service m:type="OTA">BargainFinderMax_ADRQ</m:Service>
            <m:Action>BargainFinderMax_ADRQ</m:Action>
            <m:MessageData>
                <m:MessageId>968799525452240610</m:MessageId>
                <m:Timestamp>2018-09-01T15:35:42Z</m:Timestamp>
                <m:TimeToLive>2018-09-01T16:35:42Z</m:TimeToLive>
            </m:MessageData>
            <m:DuplicateElimination/>
            <m:Description>BargainFinderMax_ADRQ</m:Description>
        </m:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1535812545543!1815120!65537</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Target="Production" Version="4.2.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="4.2.0">
    <POS>
        <Source PseudoCityCode="****">
        <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
            <CompanyName Code="TN" />
        </RequestorID>
        </Source>
    </POS>
   <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
        <DepartureDateTime>2018-09-08T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KHI" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
        <DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="3"/>
        <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
        <DepartureDateTime>2018-09-15T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KHI" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DXB" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
        <DateFlexibility NbrOfDays="3"/>
        <SegmentType Code="O" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true" >

        <CabinPref PreferLevel="Preferred" Cabin="Y" />
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <TripType Value="Return" />
            <LongConnectTime Min="780" Max="1200" Enable="true"/>
            <ExcludeCallDirectCarriers Enabled="true"/>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </TravelPreferences>
    <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
               <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
        </AirTravelerAvail>
        <PriceRequestInformation CurrencyCode="PKR" >
    <TPA_Extensions>
    </TPA_Extensions>
    </PriceRequestInformation>
    </TravelerInfoSummary>

    <TPA_Extensions>
        <IntelliSellTransaction>
            <RequestType Name="AD3"/>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
    </TPA_Extensions>

</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the design of BargainFinderMax_ADRQ in RequestType you only can include the following options:

```html
<!-- Name="AD1" will return itineraries for up to 9 alternate date combinations (+/-1 day for departure and return date). --> 
<!-- Name="AD3" will return itineraries for up to 49 alternate date combinations (up to +/-3 days for departure and return date). -->
```

When you include AD1 it will return 9 options based on a 3x3 matrix which includes the 3 options for the outbound leg and the 3 options for the inbound leg in all varying combinations.  Alternate Dates is to provide a hint that there are alternatives if you choose different date of travel you may get a lower fare.

Following the same criteria if you have and AD3 round trip request we will have 7 options for the outbound (3 options for the 3 days before + 1 option for the original date + 3 options for the days after) and 7 options for the inbound. That will make for a total of 49 options based on a 7x7 matrix.

Unfortunately this is one of the limitation of the BFM Alternate Date logic as it only produces a matrix depending on the day requested (3x3 in AD1 and 7x7 in AD3).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @PianoLontano23